# How do I get the values of multiple fileds having same name attribute using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form using ajax. In the form user can create input fields dynamically and then input data into them. I want that when form is submitted I get all the instances of input fields and then place there values in an array to pass to ajax function. How do I do that?
Here is my HMTL code snippet:

```
<input type="text" name="movies[]" >//user can create as many fields dynamically as they want to and then submit the form.
```

How do I get the values of all input fields named movies[]?

Here is my jquery code for form:

```
$("#subscription").submit(function(){

//How to get the all the input fields named movies[] values here?

$.ajax({

//Form submission logic using ajax here

});

});
```

Comment: If you intend to post multiple inputs with the same name just give them the same name (`<input type="text" name="movies" >`) (`[]`may or may not be needed) . If you then do a standard form submit the values get automatically added to an array of the name `movies` and posted. If you want to do ajax you can use `form.serialize()` which does the same. See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjtHT/) - Values get posted as `movie:Some Movie movie:Another Movie movie:3rd Movie`. On the server it should receive them as an array/collection like set of values then.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl +1 for serialize(), but the array syntax is needed as far as im aware

Comment: @user574632: You probably need it, depending on the language. I use MVC.NET and we don't need it there, the .NET model binder can deal with it fine. In PhP and other languages you might need it off course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the data in an array as follows:

```
var movies = $('input[name="movies[]"]').map(function(){
   return this.value;
}).get();
```

now you can pass your movies variable in in ajax function like:

```
$.ajax({

//Submit form here and pass your movies variable along other data you want to pass

});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what if I need this for the whole form ?  how can I make the map for the form ? and send it to the AJAX ?